# Redirecting with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a webpage that queries some data based on this parameter `search.php?state=AL`.

What I'm trying to do is write a rule in my `.htaccess` file that will:

1. translate `website.com/state/AL` into `search.php?state=AL`
2. If a user specifically request `search.php?state=AL` then translate that into `/state/AL`

I accomplished step 1 using this:

`RewriteRule ^state/([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]) /search.php?state=$1 [NC]`

How can I accomplish step 2? I know I will have to use `[R, NC]` to actually rewrite the URL, but thats where I'm stuck.

**EDIT:** Not sure if this matters but my webhost forces me form some reason to add `RewriteBase /` to the top of my `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to perform the redirection only in the case that the original request was pointed to the `/search.php?state=` URL, like so:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Externally redirect /search.php?state=XX --> /state/XX
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s/search\.php\?state=([A-Z]{2}) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/state/%1? [R=301,L]

# Internally redirect /state/XX --> /search.php?state=XX
RewriteRule ^state/([A-Z]{2}) /search.php?state=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted, but for some reason it's not working. It still shows `search.php?state=AL` in the address bar.

Comment: @Bob Dylan - Yeah, that's because I stupidly forgot to escape the question mark. I'll edit the answer. (And I forgot to kill the query string on the redirect, I added that in too)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^state/([A-Za-z][A-Za-z]) /search.php?state=$1 [NC, L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=([A-Za-z][A-Za-z])
RewriteRule ^search\.php$ /state/%1 [R=303, NC]
```

Comment: When I tried this one it gave me an Internal Server Error: `500`